# How to insert values into to mysql DataBase using Java servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

(Sorry for the amoount Of code I have, but I really don't know how much is enough)

I'm having trouble inserting values into the mysql database. I'm using Jsp files instead of html files. I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what's causing it.

```
public class AddTo extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movieDB";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "sund ";

        try {
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
            dbURL, username, password);

            } 

        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddTo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        String query = "INSERT INTO table1 " + "VALUES ('" + name + "')";
        Statement statement = null;

        statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();


        statement.executeUpdate(query);


        Movie aMovie = new Movie(request.getParameter("name"));
        request.setAttribute("user", aMovie);
        String cartRadio = request.getParameter("cartRadio");

        if ( cartRadio.equalsIgnoreCase("cartSelect") ) {

            String url = "/jsp2.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);   
        }

        if ( cartRadio.equalsIgnoreCase("listSelect")) {

            String url = "/jsp3.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        }

        if ( cartRadio.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {

            String url = "/jsp4.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        }
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddTo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddTo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private Object getServletContext() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

One error I keep getting is "incompatible typesrequired: com.mysql.jdbc.Statement found: java.sql.Statement" under where "statement = conn.createStatement();" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have the import statement

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
```

instead of

```
import java.sql.Statement;
```

This has been stated many times on this site but you should consider using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

Comment: I usually try to find similar questions before asking. Thank you for the extra links.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to cast, so don't. Also remove the import statement for the mysql Statement class - you shouldn't need that either.

Instead, first simply use the object without referring to it:

```
conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
```

Once you get that working, only then consider holding a reference to the Statement object if you really need one.